# Computer won't come out of sleep with dual monitors

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

Yesterday I installed a second ASUS VG248QE monitor to my computer connected via displayport and now when I leave my computer idle and come back, it's completely unresponsive.

It won't power on until I disconnect both monitors from DVI and displayport respectively then I can reconnect them and all works well. Sometimes when it boots back up after this happening I get a power surge detection warning. I have my monitors, computer, ethernet hub, and a lamp plugged into an old power strip. Could this be causing this weird behavior with the computer, should I buy a newer power strip or connect the second monitor to an independent outlet?

My specs:

GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB

Processor:  Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz, 3401 Mhz, 4 Core(s)

PSU: High Power HPG-600ST-F12S ATX 600W Switching Power Supply PSU 115-230V 50-60Hz

Is my GPU too weak to support these monitors? I have two ASUS VG248QE monitors one running 144hz on DVI other 60hz on displayport.

TLDR: My computer won't come back out of sleep with both monitors connected into DVI and displayport. Only after disconnecting displayport does the computer turn back on and I can reconnect it.

EDIT: I tested moving the second monitor to an independent outlet and I had the same issue trying to come back out of sleep. My computer will only come out of sleep if I disconnect the displayport.

Comment: What is your PSU and how old is it?

Comment: @computercarguy High Power HPG-600ST-F12S ATX 600W Switching Power Supply PSU 115-230V 50-60Hz Purchased last year.

Comment: The PSU and GPU should be more than enough to run the displays.  Just as a stab in the dark, have you tried switching out the power strip or unplugging the lamp?  A decent surge suppressor should cost less than $20.  I like to get the "basic" hardware variables ruled out before going too far.  I've seen other techs with >20 years experience get fouled on something like a bad/old power cord.

Comment: @computercarguy I just changed out the power surge for a modern one and it didn't work however listen to this: I decided to switch out the displayport cable for an hdmi one and all of a sudden it worked. When I switch back to the displayport the computer refuses to boot then says there is a power surge. So far smooth sailing on hdmi but I want to use displayport for 144hz.

Comment: I think I may have a faulty displayport cable on my hands here.

Comment: Ok, so that cable swap test narrows it down to, well, the cable and the ports.  Is your DisplayPort cable rated for 144hz?  Does the system come back if it's not 144hz?  Does the monitor work on another system at 144hz and come back from sleep?  Does the computer resume at 144hz with a different monitor, but same cable or different cable?

Comment: I discovered the 20th pin is enabled on my displayport cable and possibly causing my PC not to boot. I have ordered a VESA compliant one off amazon and will update by Friday night.

Comment: @computercarguy confirmed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My display port cable had the 20th pin enabled feeding power back into my GPU; it didn't like that. I replaced the cable with a VESA compliant one and my problem was solved.